# Set Response Http:InboundGateway StatusCode in Spring Integration Java DSL

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

The following bit of config accepts a HTTP POST with a JSON request body of a User instance to create, but I'm danged if I can get it to return a `201 Created`. Any ideas?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(UserService userService) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Http.inboundGateway("/users")
            .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .statusCodeFunction(f -> HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .requestPayloadType(User.class)
            .replyChannel(replyChannel())
            .requestChannel(inputChannel())
        )
        .handle((p, h) -> userService.create((User) p)).get();
}
```

I tried calling `statusCodeFunction` on the `HttpRequestHandlerEndpointSpec`, but I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: I fixed it by just replacing Http.inboundGateway with Http.inboundChannelAdapter. Can someone shed some light on why that responds with a http status and when would I use / not use inboundGateway over inboundChannelAdapter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that `statusCodeFunction` only works for inbound adapters (ie things that are one-way on the way in). Kinda begs the question of why I can call it on a *gateway*, but ho-hum...

Using `enrichHeaders` on the `IntegrationFlow` did the trick.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@Profile("integration")
public class IntegrationConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpGate() {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
        RequestMapping requestMapping = new RequestMapping();
        requestMapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
        requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/users");
        gateway.setRequestPayloadType(User.class);
        gateway.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);
        gateway.setRequestChannel(inputChannel());
        gateway.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(UserService userService) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGate()).handle((p, h) -> userService.create((User) p))
                .enrichHeaders(
                        c -> c.header(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.CREATED))
                .get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Good catch! Yep, indeed, the status code is fully related to the reply. Like we do `ResponseEntity` together with its `status`, the same is applied here for the reply. So, yes, the `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header has to be set.

Comment: I have the exact same code, but I'm still getting "No reply received within timeout"